# Salesforce CPQ - is there a list of applied Price Rules per Quote Line?

Tags: quote, cpq, pricerule

We have many complex price rules created. Now when we Calculate a quote, some of these price rules are applied, if their conditions are met. Many rules may apply on a single quote line. For developers and key-users, it is not visible at a glance, which rules has been applied.

Sometimes calculated prices are not plausible. This might be because of wrong settings in the rule itself - or because some conditions are wrong and some rules get wrongly applied or some rules should be applied but are not triggered by the implemented conditions.

Using the UI it is very hard to find mistakes or to debug test cases easily.

For debugging reasons we would like to get a list of all applied price rules per Quote Line, so that we as developers as well as the key-users can understand, which price rule has been applied in which order.

Is there an easy way to get such an list of applied rules?

What have we done so far?

- We've looked into the docs here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_price_rules_intro.htm&type=5
- We've conducted a web-search with google

None of the above brought up some helpful information.

## Workarounds?

If no such list is existing, any conceptual idea on how or where we could inject some logic to create such a list or log would help, too. E.g. a trigger or extension or whatever we could write to fill in an entry when the rule gets applied (that is when the rule fires)

Answer (score 1):

OOTB there's nothing that does this, but by adding a long text area to the QL and adding a price action that concatenates the existing string in the long text area with the price rule name of that  is firing you can achieve this.

Taking it a step further adding a very simple QCP method to log the contents of the text area can make it such that you can see the rules firing real time without having to leave the line editor.

I've used this many times when working with numerous overlapping price rules sine it makes debugging a whole lot easier.

Comment: Thanks @Austin - I did not understand the "Taking it a step further" about the simple QCP method. Can you give me a little hint or provide a link to clarify what you mean. Is that a JavaScript Method? How it can be added to the editor?